# Method to redirect incorrect URLs to HTTPS site?

Tags: html, apache, http, https

I've setup a web site on:

```
https://foo.com
```

and I would like it if traffic from the following urls:

```
http://foo.com
http://www.foo.com
https://www.foo.com
```

would be automatically redirected there.  That is if someone types one of the the lower three URLS in their browser, I would like it to immediately change the URL displayed to `https://foo.com` and I want to receive a HTTPS request on `https://foo.com` on the server, just like if the person had typed `https://foo.com`.

Which of the methods of achieving this is best?  I'm using Apache.

Also the SSL certificate is signed for `foo.com` not `www.foo.com`, is it possible to achieve the redirect from `https://www.foo.com` without issuing a certificate warning?  Or do I need to get a second certificate for `www.foo.com`?

Comment: The redirect from www.foo.com would have to be at the DNS level in order to not receive a certificate error. A CName might work, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the non SSL sites will have no problem redirecting using a rewrite in either your vhost file or your .htaccess file (assuming you have *.foo.com a server alias for foo.com).

You'll need a certificate for each of the the miss-spelled ssl urls or they'll get certificate errors when people try to connect to them.  Once that's done, you can redirect them.

Assuming the server aliases are setup and you have mod_rewrite enabled, here is the rewrite rule you need:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://foo.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When you say a rewrite - do you mean mod_rewrite?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling yes, mod_rewrite module rewrite the rewrite rule can be placed in either your httpd.conf files for the virtual host or in the docroot .htaccess file.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling exactly.  Do you have the ability to see if your server already has this module enabled?  It's pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

untested but worth a shot
append this to your httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName foo.com
        ServerAlias www.foo.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/foo
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName foo.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/foo
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/app_foo_com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/foo.ca.crt
        ErrorLog /var/log/ssl_engine.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't redirect them.  The URL displayed in the browser is still the incorrect one.